# Check UMP consent admob without activity context android

Tags: android, admob, ump

I have two questions related to implementation of [UMP](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy#request-ads)

First, after read documentation and check the sample code I can't find any method that check `consent form` without activity context is there any way to check if Consent form required or not without activity context?

Second, I need to load admob ads on `Application` class, Is there any alternative way check consent on app level and load ads in app level if consent form not required.

> Note: canRequestAds() always returns false until you have called
> requestConsentInfoUpdate()